# Fast Transfer Stream Parser EWS Export Items

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I wanted to parse data that we get after EWS Exchange Export Items, I am not able to find any code that does this, do comment if anyone knows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it is not documented, but it is essentially a serialized array of MAPI properties intermingled with page breaks.

You can see it in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click GetItem button on the EWS group on the OutlookSpy ribbon and go to the ExportItems tab.

[Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am also its author) allows to import and export FTS data via `RDOMail.Import/SaveAs(..., olFts)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I saw your answer on a similar question and had used Outlook Spy to view the parsed contents, also I saw that I was able to upload a fts data file and see the parsed contents, using getfolder in outlook spy, but currently the issue I am facing is that I have the fts data AwAXAAEAAACwhBoAIAAAAEkAUABNAC4AQQBwAHAAbwBpAG4Ad.... ( in this format) i tried copying it to notepad and saving it as fts and then uploading it to outlook spy get folder to see the parsed items but it did not work ,is there any other step that i have to do before uploading the fts data?

Comment: Hey, I just found that while uploading i can change the format of the file to fts base 64 text file and parse the same..